# Two module federation plugin and shared scope

Tags: webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to export 2 components through module federation in same remote app like:

remote webpack:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'remote1',
    filename: 'remoteEntry1.js',
    exposes: {
      './Component1': './src/components/component1',
    },
    shared: {
      react: {
        singleton: true,
      },
      'react-dom': {
        singleton: true,
      },
    },
  }),


new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'remote2',
    filename: 'remoteEntry2.js',
    exposes: {
      './Component2': './src/components/component2',
    },
    shared: {
      react: {
        singleton: true,
      },
      'react-dom': {
        singleton: true,
      },
      'react-router-dom': {
        singleton: true,
      },
    },
  }),
```

These are being used in 2 different host apps host1 for remote1 and host2 for remote2.
I want to make react-router-dom singleton only with remote2, but in this setup with 2 module federation plugins, react-router-dom is marked as singleton even in remoteEntry1.

How can we make different shared scope for different hosts?

Tried 2 different plugins, but shared scope of both plugins is merged and host1 even while importing only remote1, gets shared objects from remote2 as well.